# if (strcmp(file_name, "stdout") == 0)?

Tags: c

I have the following code that creates random numbers and send the output to a filename given by the user. 
However I cannot grasp from line 19 on. According to the documentation, when you want to compare two strings to see if they are equal, then you use from the standard library in C the function strcmp, which takes two arguments (string1 and string2), and if they are equal then the result is 0. In the if statemente I have two strings, the first is the file_name given by the user when prompt to do so, and a string "stdout", could anyone tell me how this comparison makes sense?

```
if (strcmp(file_name, "stdout") == 0)
```

Additionally, in line 26 you find 
`if (i % 6 == 1)`
which is the modulus (what's remains after performing the division for the numbers in the for loop, and if the remaining is 1 then it makes a fprintf, that I only can understand as printing columns for the rand numbers that will be generated.

Is it correct?

```
#include <stdio.h> /* include libraries */ 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() /* declares function main as void */
{
     char file_name[100]; /*declares an array of name file_name
     with 100 elements */
     int i, n; /*declares two integers of name i and n */
     FILE *fp; /* declares a variables of type pointer to file */

     printf("\nthis program creates random numbers."); /*prints message */
     printf("\n\nhow many would you like?   "); /*prints question */
     scanf("%d", &n); /* gets user input and stores answer in address of 
     variable n */
     printf("in what file would you like them? "); /*prints question*/
     scanf("%s", file_name); /*gets user input and store it as string
     into the variable array of name file_name */
     if (strcmp(file_name, "stdout") == 0) /*if the comparison between 
     file_name and "stdout" is equal to 0 (both strings are equal)*/
         fp = stdout; /* it assigns the pointer to file to standard output*/
     else /*if not then */
         fp = fopen(file_name, "w");/*opens the file_name in write modus*/
     for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {/*initializes for loop from one to the value
     of n that you entered*/
         if (i % 6 == 1) /*if the residuo of i / 6 is 1 for instance 13/6 = 1*/
             fprintf(fp, "\n");/* it prints the information from the ?? */
         fprintf(fp, "%12d", rand());
     }
 }
```

Comment: Note: The line numbers here really don't help. Anyone wanting to use this code to test will have to remove them all.

Comment: It's also tradition to use `"-"` as the name for "write to STDOUT".

Comment: When the file name `"stdout"` is entered, that is a cue not to send to a file by that name but to the `stdout` predefined file, usually a console.

Comment: What's confusing about [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)? Check the documentation whenever you've got questions.

Comment: It comes from an old book called A Book on C by Kelley and Pohl

Answer (score -1):

```
char file_name[100]="smth.txt:;
if (strcmp(file_name, "stdout") == 0){
}//....


if (i % 6 == 0)
       fprintf(fp, "\n");
fprintf(fp, "%12d", rand());
```

Comment: In the string of the file name you also have an extension

Comment: Instead of just dumping some code into an answer could you explain the problem and how your code fixes it?

Comment: I think you miss the point that `scanf("%s", file_name);` is entering a file name from the user. It's not defined in the code.